# What actually happened to Lukas?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-bouncer

I saw that Lukas starts the car at the end of [*The Bouncer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bouncer_(film)). Well, it seems that he was alive that time but not sure about that.

Can somebody explain?